# printk's in under a nanosecond? - getnstimeofday() questions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, nstimer

I'm doing module programming. I have a time measuring I want to make on the performance impact of some printk's I'm doing. I have a setup in code like this.

In "declare-y" beginning part of the code:

```
struct timespec ts_start,ts_end,test_of_time;
```

In a method:

```
{
    //..other stuff
    getnstimeofday(&ts_start);
    printk("mkdir being hijacked\n");
    printk("pid is %d ", current->pid);
    printk("call #: 39 \n");
    printk("user_id of process: %d, effuid: %d\n\n", current->uid, current->euid);
    getnstimeofday(&ts_end);
    test_of_time = timespec_sub(ts_end,ts_start);
    printk("%lu", test_of_time.tv_nsec);
    return val;
}
```

I dmesg and strangely see the value 0. I highly doubt it took 0 nanoseconds for this to happen. What is amiss here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of the kernel are you using?  You likely don't actually have nanosecond resolution on your timer.  If you want to measure the time the printks take, you should run them in a loop so that they take a finite and measurable amount of time.  It won't be completely accurate (e.g. the first prink while likely be slower than subsequent ones due to cache misses, etc.), but that should give you a ballpark idea.

If you want to see why this happens, try allocating a big buffer, spinning in a loop writing the values of getnstimeofday into the buffer for a while, and then outputting the buffer to somewhere you can analyze it.  You'll probably be able to see the actual clock resolution in the data.